# Bending horizontal bars of Iron fence

Tags: fence, metal, gates, cast-iron

We have a metal fence in front of the house and it has very strong iron rods both vertically and horizontally.

The issue is with the horizontal iron rod as its bend and also its vending on the other side is broken, so its sticking out on one side.

I tried to bend it with hand but its too strong and doesn't move. When I hit it with hammer I am not able to hit it from behind due to the mesh behind, ( the bend side is on the back), so if I hit it from the front the whole rod vibrates and its not helpful. See the below pics for clear details.

Any suggestions would be great, thanks

[image: There is a bend at the left arrow pointing place]

[image: And its a very wide bend]

Comment: you probably have to take the mesh off. it looks like it was added after the fence was built to keep a small animal contained.

Comment: You would probably need to remove that top pipe and put it in a bender to bend it back. Even if you do that, it'll probably never be straight, just "close". A blacksmith may be able to heat it and roll it straight again. It might be easier and more cost effective to replace it.

Comment: BTW- You'll probably need to weld the bar back against the post once it's straightened/replaced, so you may as well hire this out to someone who can do both tasks for you. I'm presuming you can't weld because you'd probably know how to go about straightening the bar if you did.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to straighten he metal pipe is to heat it with a Mapp gas torch. Apply the flame to the crimped pipe end until it begins to glow orange.

Slowly and steadily push the free end back into position. You may have to push the pipe past it's final position so as to compensate for it springing back slighly.

Comment: You might want to grind/sand the paint off the area to be heated instead of letting it burn off and produce some nasty smelling (if not also toxic) fumes.

Answer (score 1):

First find out what has fractured inside the pipe ; possibly aluminum or concrete . It will need to be repaired. A hammer is completely useless; as noted , you need a clamp or chainfall ( cable with ratchet) to pull it straight. It does seem like a contractor job ,partly depending on what is fractured .

Answer (score -1):

Use wood blocks and C-clamps to straighten the bar.

The rough sketch hopefully illustrates what I mean.

C-clamps are not shown in drawing.

[image]

C-clamp
[image]